# Is it possible to run 64bit kernel on 32bit Linux Mint with NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: 64-bit, linux-mint, kernel, 32-bit

I have found several forum posts and SE questions ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/152798/2385)) where this seems possible, but my attempt has failed. I've tried the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic:amd64
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

However, when I boot with the 64bit kernel, my keyboard and mouse don't work for some reason (terminal or X). Also, the X login screen resolution is wrong, but I guess that's because I'd need to install 64bit NVIDIA drivers for the new kernel. I also don't see any obvious errors in syslog, although it's shorter than regular 32bit boot.

I'm basically trying to do this becasue I've received a 64bit game on Steam as a gift, and I'm running 32bit OS because wine games work (better) on 32 bits.

Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to dual boot or reinstall?

Comment: @Ramhound Well blimey that's a shame. Can I assume that the linked forum post is talking about a different use case, and I misunderstood? In any case, if you magically turn your comment into an answer, a wizard may come and accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some forum posts suggest that this is possible, I couldn't find a reliable way of doing it.

Ended up installing Mint 64bit over my previous OS.

Luckily, the status of WINE 32bit gaming has improved significantly since my last attempt, so everything is working fine.